# Calculating the mass of the earth using a BigInteger

Tags: java, math, physics, biginteger

I am trying to calculate the mass of the earth using a BigInteger, however something doesn't add up, literally.

The formula I am using to calculate the mass of the earth is: M = ar2/G = 5.98 × 1024 kg. a being the acceleration of gravity (9.8 m/s squared), r being the radius of the earth ((6.4) *(10^6)), and Big-G ((6.673) * (10^-11)) the gravitational constant.

The value I should be getting is: 5.97219 × 10^24 kg = 5,972,190,000,000,000,000,000,000, however the value I am currently outputting is: -9353. Obviously a huge difference, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is what I have so far...

```
double bigG = (6.673) * (10^-11);
double radiusSquared = 6371^2;
double acceleration = (10^2); (obviously rounded here from 9.8)
double mass = (acceleration*radiusSquared)/bigG;

BigInteger massBig = new BigDecimal(mass).toBigInteger();
System.out.println("mass of earth: "+massBig);'
```

I am not sure if I simply got some of inputs wrong, or if I am failing to recognize some underlying process of Java, as I am new to both Java and Physics.

Thank you

---

### update

Okay I did what you said and seemed to have solved part of the problem... 
Here is the updated code:

```
public static void getPlanetMass(){
    double bigG = (6.673) * (Math.pow(10, -11));
    double radiusSquared =  (Math.pow(6371, 2));
    double acceleration =  (Math.pow(9.8,2)); //(obviously rounded here from 9.8)
    double mass = (acceleration*radiusSquared)/bigG;
    BigInteger massBig = new BigDecimal(mass).toBigInteger();
    System.out.println("mass of earth: "+massBig);
}
```

Current Output: 58,417,939,781,807,300,608
Correct Output: 5,973,600,000,000,000,000,000,000

So being that I am about a million off here, I am still missing a few orders of magnitude, anyone versed in math/physics would help here.

Comment: (1) radius is 6371 km, i.e. 6371000 meters. You're lacking a few zeros. (2) Do not square the acceleration; only the radius gets squared. (1) and (2) are bugs. Here is a slight improvement. (3) Write bigG = 6.673e-11 (no need to call Math.pow to compute a power of 10).

Comment: ah I knew I overlooked something to do with a power of 10 somewhere in there, or in this case 1000. Thank you

Comment: Wow! Seems like you found proof for the hollow earth hypothesis!! ;)   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hollow_Earth

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`^` Is not the power but the Binary `XOR`.

> Binary XOR Operator copies the bit if it is set in one operand but not
>   both.

You want

```
Math.pow(x, y);
```

Comment: x being the integer, and y being the exponent, I take it?